# @Html.DropDownList not re rendering when selected value is changed

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I've got an issue with the below code.

```
@model ShoeFormViewModel
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ToDo", "shoecontroller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ShoesForm" }))
        {
<th>
//1: Drop down the list I'm using to test this drop-down list 2 and 3 should reflect the state of this dropdown.
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Shoes.First().Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "h7 alert-link" })
                    @Html.DropDownList("SelectedShoeId",
                        new SelectList((IEnumerable<ShoeModel>)Model.Shoes, "Id", "Name", Model.Options.SelectedShoeId),
                        new { @class = "dropleft", onchange = "document.getElementById('ShoesForm').submit();" })
                </td>
                <td>
//2: this doe's not reflect 1's state but should.      
                    @Html.DropDownList("SelectedShoesId",
                   new SelectList((IEnumerable<ShoeModel>)Model.Shoes, "Id", "Name", Model.Options.SelectedShoeId),
                                              new { @class = "dropleft", onchange = "document.getElementById('ShoesForm').submit();" })


//3: This Reflects 1's state. 
                    @Html.DropDownList("SelectedShoeId2",
new SelectList((IEnumerable<ShoeModel>)Model.Shoes, "Id", "Name", Model.Options.SelectedShoeId),
new { @class = "dropleft", onchange = "document.getElementById('ShoesForm').submit();" })

                </td>
</th>
}
```

When changing the selected value in the first dropdown box both the first and third rerender with the newly selected value. The middle drop-down list retains state and doe's not rerender to the newly selected value.

I have tried to change the expression string at the front of the second dropdown list and this causes the dropdown list to display the selected value, however, "SelectedShoesId" is the property that I need that select list to update in the model.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Edit:

The view model looks like this:

```
public class ShoeFormViewModel
    {
        public FilterPageOptions Options { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ShoeModel> Shoes { get; set; }
    }
```

Shoes model looks like

```
    public class ShoeModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Shoe")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool? IsActive { get;set; }
    }
```

FilterPageOptions has been simplified to

```
 public class FilterPageOptions 
    {
        public int? SelectedShoeId { get; set; } = 1;
    }
```

The controller has been simplified to:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> ToDo(FilterPageOptions options)
        {
            var model = new ShoeFormViewModel();

            model.Options = options;

            model.Shoes = await shoeService.GetShoesAsync();

            return View(model);
        }
```

And yet Dropdown list 2 still doe's not reflect 1 and three.

Comment: Your description is not very clear and the code is not complete, could you please provide us more information inluding the whole view codes, related models and controller actions? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: it would help if you would cleanup your code. remove all the comments that are not neccessary to understand the problem.

Comment: Hi, Guys thanks for taking the time to read and respond to my problem. As you can see I've edited my question to help highlight the issue.

Comment: onchange = "document.getElementById('ShoesForm').submit();". can you show us this form?

Comment: @mj1313 the form only consists of the three dropdown lists. I have, however, added the using statement around the form.

Comment: I have tested your codes. It seems the three dropdownlists are the same except the id and name.So the result is when I change the value of the first dropdownlist, the 2nd and the 3rd will change like the 1st.